# Fill Color of Multiple Drawlines that Intersect Forming Closed Shape

Tags: java, colors, fill, stroke

I needed to draw a Car using Java and Graphics2D. I used multiple    basicstrokes to come up with the shape of the car. How do I fill it with color? An example would be drawing 3 lines in the shape of a triangle and then wanting to fill it with color.

Comment: you may need to use `polygon` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html

Comment: @FastSnail I wonder why this is still recommended on an oracle site. It seems to be legacy and out-dated. The proper way would be to use a `Path2D` here.

Comment: @Marco13 oops never new that ..

Answer (score 3):

You can not simply fill a shape that was only created by *drawing* three lines. You have to *define* the shape, including all the lines that it consists of.

How exactly this is implemented depends on serveal factors. For example, whether you want to use the same stroke for all three lines, or whether they need different strokes.

It could be helpful if you had already provided some information of how exactly you are drawing the lines at the moment. I'll try to make a guess here...

So **assuming** that your current code roughly looks like this:

```
void paintCar(Graphics2D g)
{
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    // Draw the triangle    
    g.drawLine(100,100,200,100);
    g.drawLine(100,200,150, 50);
    g.drawLine(150, 50,100,100);
}
```

the easiest way to additionally fill this triangle would be to change it as follows:

```
void paintCar(Graphics2D g)
{
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);


    Path2D path = new Path2D();

    // Build the triangle    
    path.append(new Line2D.Double(100,100,200,100), false);
    path.append(new Line2D.Double(100,200,150, 50), true);
    path.append(new Line2D.Double(150, 50,100,100), true);

    // Draw the triangle
    g.draw(path);

    // Fill the triangle, with a different color
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fill(path);
}
```

### But note...

... that there are more elegant and concise ways of achieving this. Usually, one would not append individual `Line2D` segments, but simply use the `Path2D` to build the shape:

```
void paintCar(Graphics2D g)
{
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    // Build the triangle    
    Path2D path = new Path2D();
    path.moveTo(100,100);
    path.lineTo(200,100);
    path.lineTo(150, 50); 
    path.closePath();

    // Draw the triangle
    g.draw(path);

    // Fill the triangle, with a different color
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fill(path);
}
```

So if you have the coordinates of your shape in an appropriate form (maybe stored as a list of `Point2D` objects), you may more easily build a shape that you can draw and fill then.